# How to custom message validator with Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am making an API that allows users to input some information like email, phone number, address ...
But if users input wrong phone nums, the validate error is

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "phone": [
      "The phone has already been taken."
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see the message returns is

```
"message": "The given data was invalid."
```

. But the message I expect is `The phone has already been taken`. How can I custom the message as I expect? With an email validator, the message is the same but the key is `email`. The message I expect is

```
"message": "The ... has already been taken. "
```

I'm using laravel 8 and validate in Request
Example a function `rules()`

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'profile_img' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:' . config('filesystems.max_upload_size'),
            'name' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'phone' => [
                'required',
                'numeric',
                new UpdatePhoneRule(User::TYPE_CLIENT),
            ],
            'email' => [
                'nullable',
                'email',
                new UpdateEmailRule(User::TYPE_CLIENT),
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Request php file you can use this function failedValidation() and pass in a Validator. This way you can alter or customize the response if validation fails.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['status'=>'failed',
                                                    'message'=>'unprocessable entity',
                                                    'errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422));
    }
```

Sample response is here..

```
{
"status": "failed",
"message": "unprocessable entity",
"errors": [
    "The name must be a string.",
    "One or more users is required"
 ]
}
```

As you can see the message is changed now you can do whatever you want on the response message.

Also you can try this

```
$validator->errors()->messages()[keyname]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `unique` in your validation

```
$this->validate(
    $request, 
    [   
        'email'             => 'required|unique:your_model_names',
        'phone'             => 'required|unique:your_model_names'
    ],
    [   
        'email.required'    => 'Please Provide Your Email Address For Better Communication, Thank You.',
        'email.unique'      => 'Sorry, This Email Address Is Already Used By Another User. Please Try With Different One, Thank You.',
        'phone.required' => 'Your custom message',
        'phone.unique'      => 'The phone has already been taken'
    ]
);
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not the result I expect. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the lang file: `resources/lang/en/validation.php`. If all you want to do is change, for example, the message for a unique rule on an email field across the entire app you can do:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
    'email' => [
        'unique' => 'This email is already registered...etc',
    ]
],
```